# ArcGIS JSAPI draw toolbar tooltips not displayed in IE10

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, map-drawing, internet-explorer

I am experiencing an issue where the draw toolbar tooltips are not displayed in Internet Explorer 10 when using the ArcGIS Javascript API.

Try the following example in Internet Explorer 10 and Google Chrome (draw a polygon and see what I mean)
http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/samples/graphics_add/

Has anyone else experienced this issue and is there any way to get the tooltips to display in Internet Explorer 10?

Answer (score 3):

The updated answer to this question is to update your JSAPI version. I've tested IE10 with the latest API and it works as expected.

Comment: This is the right answer

Answer (score 1):

I checked today, and I'm having the same issue. Digging into the generated html, the tooltip div isn't even generated in IE10.

[image]

If you view the page in compatibility mode with IE9 document standards or lower, the tooltips show up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with a zoom navigation tool.  I'm not seeing the tooltip issue on my machine, running ie10, but forcing IE10 into an earlier rendering engine using the X-UA-Compatible meta tag (Firefox, Chrome, etc. will ignore this tag) took care of the issues I was having with the navigation tools.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this issue with Dojo popups in general and found that IE and Firefox have stricter CSS parsing rules and so rules like 'top:32' without the 'px' suffix get dropped with an error that says "Error in parsing value for property 'top'. Declaration dropped". So, the tooltip's position is never set which causes it to remain out of view.